# Change git account terminal

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

Since I have multiple git accounts (`work_account` and `personal_account`) I am trying to change to my personal account by running:

```sh
git config --global user.name 'personal_account'
git config --global user.email 'personal_account@gmail.com'
```

And:

```sh
ssh-add ~/.ssh/personal_account_key
```

But after all of that, the command `ssh -T git@github.com` keeps displaying that I am authenticated with my work account:

```sh
# ssh -T git@github.com
Hi work_account! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

How can I change it?

Comment: Check this out: https://gist.github.com/oanhnn/80a89405ab9023894df7

Comment: `git config` has nothing to do with authentication with GitHub; those are just the name and address used to create a commit locally. You may still have your work key in your SSH agent listed ahead of your personal key, which means `ssh` will use that first, and when it succeeds, it won't try using your personal key. What you want to do is define different *aliases* for `github.com` that are associated with different SSH keys and use that as the address for work vs personal repositories.